# Сохранение позиции CSS translate3d при переключении классов

Tags: javascript, css, css3, html5, анимация

У меня есть бесконечное прокручивание фонового изображения в `div`, как вы можете видеть в нижеприведенном сниппете.

Идея этого заключается в том, что это временная шкала, и я могу изменить скорость, т.е. : нормальная скорость, быстрая, медленная и даже реверс.
Используя `javascript`, я могу успешно изменять `speed class`, который у меня есть для `div`, и изображение будет успешно обновляться со скоростью и направлением, которые я задам.

Однако моя проблема в том, что когда я меняю класс, я теряю относительную позицию `translate3d` изображения, так как класс изменяется, местоположение фонового изображения сбрасывается, а затем запускается новая анимация.

Я попытался рассмотреть  несколько способов исключительно с точки зрения `css`, попробовав `complete swap` классов, а также запустив один класс в полное время и применив выбранную анимацию в качестве дополнительного класса, однако я не могу выяснить, как сохранить относительное фоновое положение при применении нового класса.

Как я могу сохранить местоположение фоновых изображений, когда я меняю класс, чтобы он не выглядел так, как-будто изображение прыгает с одной позиции на другую?

```css
.timeline_frame {
  width: 100%;
  min-width: 1500px;
  background-color: #444;
  height: 250px;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  margin: auto auto;
  position: relative;
}

.timeline {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  top: 0;
  margin: auto auto;
  width: 1500px;
  height: 200px;
}

.timeline_container {
  width: 1500px;
  height: 200px;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
}

.timeline_background {
  background: url("https://www.aidanwardman.com/timeline-bg.png") repeat-x;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  width: 3000px;
  height: 200px;
  vertical-align: bottom;
}

.timeline_speed_normal {
  animation: slide 20s linear infinite;
}

.timeline_speed_slow {
  animation: slide 40s linear infinite;
}

.timeline_speed_reverse {
  animation: slide-reverse 2s linear infinite;
}

@keyframes slide {
  0% {
    transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
  }
  100% {
    transform: translate3d(-1500px, 0, 0);
  }
}

@keyframes slide-reverse {
  0% {
    transform: translate3d(-1500px, 0, 0);
  }
  100% {
    transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
  }
}

.button_frame {
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  margin: auto;
  width: 400px;
  padding: 20px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="button_frame">
  <button id="forward-normal">Forward Normal</button>
  <button id="forward-slow">Forward Slow</button>
  <button id="reverse">Reverse</button>
</div>
<div class="timeline_frame">
  <div class="timeline">
    <div class="timeline_container">
      <div class="timeline_background timeline_speed_normal"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<script>
  $("#forward-normal").click(function() {
    $(".timeline_background").removeClass("timeline_speed_fast timeline_speed_slow timeline_speed_reverse").addClass("timeline_speed_normal");
  });
  $("#forward-slow").click(function() {
    $(".timeline_background").removeClass("timeline_speed_fast timeline_speed_normal timeline_speed_reverse").addClass("timeline_speed_slow");
  });
  $("#reverse").click(function() {
    $(".timeline_background").removeClass("timeline_speed_fast timeline_speed_slow timeline_speed_normal").addClass("timeline_speed_reverse");
  });
</script>
```

Comment: ассоциация:https://stackoverflow.com/q/53454162/7394871

Comment: Сейчас бы в конце 2018-го только использовать jQuery, особенно версию 2.1.1.

Comment: Тем более для манипуляции с классами... Почитайте https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/Element/classList

Answer (score 2):

Я бы смоделировал такую вещь, используя `transition` вместо `animation`:

```css
.timeline_frame {
  width: 100%;
  min-width: 1500px;
  background-color: #444;
  height: 250px;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  margin: auto auto;
  position: relative;
}

.timeline {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  top: 0;
  margin: auto auto;
  width: 1500px;
  height: 200px;
}

.timeline_container {
  width: 1500px;
  height: 200px;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
}

.timeline_background {
  background: url("https://www.aidanwardman.com/timeline-bg.png") repeat-x;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  width: 3000px;
  height: 200px;
  vertical-align: bottom;
  transition:10s all;
}

.timeline_speed_normal {
  transform: translate3d(-1500px, 0, 0);
}

.timeline_speed_slow {
  transition:30s all;
  transform: translate3d(-1501px, 0, 0);
}

.timeline_speed_reverse {
  transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
}

.button_frame {
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  margin: auto;
  width: 400px;
  padding: 20px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="button_frame">
  <button id="forward-normal">Forward Normal</button>
  <button id="forward-slow">Forward Slow</button>
  <button id="reverse">Reverse</button>
</div>
<div class="timeline_frame">
  <div class="timeline">
    <div class="timeline_container">
      <div class="timeline_background"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<script>
  $("#forward-normal").click(function() {
    $(".timeline_background").removeClass("timeline_speed_fast timeline_speed_slow timeline_speed_reverse").addClass("timeline_speed_normal");
  });
  $("#forward-slow").click(function() {
    $(".timeline_background").removeClass("timeline_speed_fast timeline_speed_normal timeline_speed_reverse").addClass("timeline_speed_slow");
  });
  $("#reverse").click(function() {
    $(".timeline_background").removeClass("timeline_speed_fast timeline_speed_slow timeline_speed_normal").addClass("timeline_speed_reverse");
  });
</script>
```